# How to save TextBox value input (from UserForm) to a cell on a sheet?

Tags: c#, excel

[image]

I have a form that looks like this. My goal is to have the 13 textboxes/comboboxes to be added into an excel sheet. Also, I have 2 buttons below this which didnt show up in the picture called 'Save' and 'Add' - Save is pretty self explanatory. Add is to save the input from the UserForm and put it into the excel row with the appropriate headers, Clear the UserForm, and finally, prep the user to input data again that will go into the line below. Here is my code so far within the add button:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oXL;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook oWB;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet oSheet;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range oRng;
    int num;

    public Form1()
    {
        oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        oXL.Visible = true;

        oWB = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook)(oXL.Workbooks.Add(""));
        oSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        num++;

        oSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "UserName";
        oSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Workstation Name";
        oSheet.Cells[1, 3] = "Manufacturer";
        oSheet.Cells[1, 4] = "Model";
        oSheet.Cells[1, 5] = "Serial";
        oSheet.Cells[1, 6] = "CPU";
        oSheet.Cells[1, 7] = "RAM";
        oSheet.Cells[1, 8] = "OS";
        oSheet.Cells[1, 9] = "Version";
        oSheet.Cells[1, 10] = "Microsoft Office";
        oSheet.Cells[1, 11] = "Recommendations";
        oSheet.Cells[1, 12] = "Comments";

        oSheet.get_Range("A1", "L1").Font.Bold = true;
        oSheet.get_Range("A1", "L1").VerticalAlignment =
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter;

        string[,] saNames = new string[100, 13];

        saNames[num, 0] = txtUsername1.Text;
        saNames[num, 1] = txtWorkName1.Text;
        saNames[num, 2] = cbxManufac.Text;
        saNames[num, 3] = cbxMachType.Text;
        saNames[num, 4] = txtModel.Text;
        saNames[num, 5] = txtSerial.Text;
        saNames[num, 6] = txtCPU.Text;
        saNames[num, 7] = cbxRAM.Text;
        saNames[num, 8] = cbxOS.Text;
        saNames[num, 9] = txtVersion.Text;
        saNames[num, 10] = txtMcstOffice.Text;
        saNames[num, 11] = txtRecomend.Text;
        saNames[num, 12] = txtComments.Text;

        oSheet.get_Range("A2", "L1000").Value = saNames;
    }
```

The issue I am having is that my add button doesn't save the input into the excel cells, it disappears, I am not sure what I am doing wrong so I decided to ask people who perhaps have come across this issue before.

Also I seem to start at row "A3" instead of "A2" a little odd

Comment: when you step through the debugger is `saNames` filled with the right content?

Comment: if you create each time a new array `string[,] saNames = new string[100, 13];` then with the second click the information in this array from the first click will disappear

Comment: @MongZhu ooooh, how do I fix this?

Comment: it depends on how you structure your program and flow. But in general you could use it as a field inside the class like `num` and initialize it in the `FormLoad` event.
ps, so you expect no more than 100 entries?

Comment: @MongZhu to be honest I would like the user to create as many entries as they want, I am just not sure how to code that, I am still learning

Comment: may be you also should consider to make an own method that creates your Excel File with all the headers, because you create them also each time when the button is clicked

Comment: I don't know much about excel unfortunately, but does `oSheet.get_Range("A2", "L1000").Value = saNames;` ad the values to the file?

Comment: @MongZhu it does add the values to the file but it disappears, I am currently trying some other methods

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114038/discussion-between-mong-zhu-and-havoux).

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert in this excel acrobatics but you could try this

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oXL;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook oWB;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet oSheet;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range oRng;
    int num = 1;

    public Form1()
    {
        oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        oXL.Visible = true;

        oWB = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook)(oXL.Workbooks.Add(""));
        oSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // here you create the Headers once the Form is loaded
        initHeaders();
    }

    // a Method to create the Headers in the file
    private void initHeaders()
    {
        oSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "UserName";
        oSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Workstation Name";
        oSheet.Cells[1, 3] = "Manufacturer";
        oSheet.Cells[1, 4] = "Model";
        oSheet.Cells[1, 5] = "Serial";
        oSheet.Cells[1, 6] = "CPU";
        oSheet.Cells[1, 7] = "RAM";
        oSheet.Cells[1, 8] = "OS";
        oSheet.Cells[1, 9] = "Version";
        oSheet.Cells[1, 10] = "Microsoft Office";
        oSheet.Cells[1, 11] = "Recommendations";
        oSheet.Cells[1, 12] = "Comments";

        oSheet.get_Range("A1", "L1").Font.Bold = true;
        oSheet.get_Range("A1", "L1").VerticalAlignment =
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter;

    }
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        num++;

        // you actually need only a one dimensional array    
        string[] saNames = new string[13];

        saNames[0] = txtUsername1.Text;
        saNames[1] = txtWorkName1.Text;
        saNames[2] = cbxManufac.Text;
        saNames[3] = cbxMachType.Text;
        saNames[4] = txtModel.Text;
        saNames[5] = txtSerial.Text;
        saNames[6] = txtCPU.Text;
        saNames[7] = cbxRAM.Text;
        saNames[8] = cbxOS.Text;
        saNames[9] = txtVersion.Text;
        saNames[10] = txtMcstOffice.Text;
        saNames[11] = txtRecomend.Text;
        saNames[12] = txtComments.Text;

        // Try to increment just the position in the file
        string startposition = "A" + num.toString();
        oSheet.get_Range(startposition , "L1000").Value = saNames;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)    
{
    int _lastRow = oSheet.Range["A" + oSheet.Rows.Count].End[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlDirection.xlUp].Row + 1;

    oSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 1] = txtUsername1.Text;
    oSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 2] = txtWorkName1.Text;
    oSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 3] = cbxManufac.Text;
    oSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 4] = cbxMachType.Text;
    oSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 5] = txtModel.Text;
    oSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 6] = txtSerial.Text;
    oSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 7] = txtCPU.Text;
    oSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 8] = cbxRAM.Text;
    oSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 9] = cbxOS.Text;
    oSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 10] = txtVersion.Text;
    oSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 11] = txtMcstOffice.Text;
    oSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 12] = txtRecomend.Text;
    oSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 13] = txtComments.Text;

}
```

I fixed it :o

Comment: may be you could comment on what the first line is doing in detail. That would help other people who look up this post in future